# Minimalistic terminal music player that can play all my files randomly

Tags: terminal, software-rec, music-player

I'm looking for a terminal music player. `mpg321/mpg123` is quite what I need, but it can't [play all my music directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2588/how-to-pass-the-result-of-find-as-a-list-of-files) (which contains child directories). `cmus` seems to be a bit of an overkill, as there are a lot of features I never use.

I just need a program, that I can give it my music directory and perhaps a `--random` flag, then it will play everything with random orders. Can someone point out what options I have?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can easily wrap up a script using *find* and *rl* (package *randomize-lines* on debian).

Something along the lines of:

```
find "$1" -type f -name *.mp3 | rl | while read FILE; do mpg123 "$FILE"; done
```

Comment: ha! I like this one the best :D

Comment: If you don't have `rl`, `sort -R` accomplishes the same thing

Comment: @MrShunz I think it is `find "$1" -type f -name *.mp3`, typo?

Comment: @phunehehe eheh yeah typed that from memory...

Comment: @Michael Mrozek that's even better ... sort should be present by default in most distros...

Comment: @MrShunz do you know you can edit your post? there should be an "edit" link below your answer where you can fix the typo

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the command.

Answer (score 7):

I use [gst123](http://space.twc.de/~stefan/gst123.php) as a command line player. Point it at the parent directory and it will shuffle through it and the child directories with the -z flag.  I run it like this.

```
 gst123 -z ~/Music
```

Comment: this is actually nice, I'll try it some time, maybe when it's in the gentoo portage tree

Answer (score 5):

There is moc - Music on console. It's simpler than mpd, but ships with embedded ncurses frontend. You can use ncurses TUI with mocp or talk to the server directly.

Of course it can't do all the nifty stuff mpd can do, like network streaming, different outputs simultaneosly, etc. But as a simple console player on local machine it's pretty usefull. It works without initial configuration, in contrast to mpd. The server starts automatically when mocp is called w/o parameters, or can be started manually.

start the server

```
mocp -S
```

tell the server to append (-a) a music folder to the playlist
and to switch shuffle on (-o shuffle)
and to start playing (-p)

```
mocp -o shuffle -p -a ~/mymusicfolder
```

I've 9.2 GB flac files and it only need 6 sec to load it from sata 1 hdd.
from my sata 2 ssd it's instant.
My output is alsa. (Didn't had to configure)

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Moc

Comment: Currently my `mpd` runs "unconfigured", just with built-in defaults and information detected on startup.

Comment: oh, weird. According to https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mpd the user has to setup the files/folders with proper permissions, point to them in the config file and setup the sound devices at least. Maybe its destribution dependent.

Comment: Tried it again from zero and now indeed not created the `~/.mpd` stuff. However my current working conf was certainly not created by me, as the files not match my naming convention. The audio_output device left unconfigured until present days and `mpd` automatically detects it on startup. BTW, it's also Alsa. Well, accept my upvote with apologies.

Comment: Ah, thx for pointing out that audio output is autodetected, good to know ^^ Apology accepted with a comment vote up ;) 
We all are here to learn.

Answer (score 4):

You might try [MPD](http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/Music_Player_Daemon_Wiki) it consists of a server backend and a separate frontend (which may but needn't run on the same machine). There are several great command line clients for it (see http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/Clients)

Answer (score 1):

I've spent some time fiddling with diverse minimalistic music players and today find myself especially partial to the relatively recent [xmms2](http://xmms2.org/wiki/Main_Page), a descendant (somewhat) of the venerable xmms music player.

It is a robust client-server application, designed to run full-featured from the command line or from multiple graphical clients, play practically any music encoding available, manage music collections while taking up as little processor time as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I just use mplayer. I generated a list of files from my music folders and mplayer can take that file as a playlist and play it in random order.

Answer (score 0):

Through this shell, your music library will be played randomly, without repeating any songs until all have been played.

The history of songs played is recorded in the file `*. Sh.his`. This history is reset automatically if you added a song to the music library or have already heard all the songs of your library, generating a new random list ever. Whenever you want you can reset the history is deleting the file `*. Sh.his`.

```
#!/bin/bash

#-----------------------------------INFO----------------------------------------------------------

#Through this shell, your music library will be played randomly, without repeating any songs until all have been played. 
#The history of songs played is recorded in the file "*. Sh.his". 
#This history is reset automatically if you added a song to the music library or have already heard all the songs of your library, 
#generating a new random list ever. Whenever you want you can reset the history is deleting the file "*. Sh.his".

#Press "q" to skip song
#Press "p" to pause song and resume song

#------------------------------CONFIGURATION------------------------------------------------------

#mplayer package needed (For debian/Ubuntu/Mint: "$ apt-get install mplayer")

#Select your music library path (all recursive folders will be included in the .mp3 files search):
path="/media/Datos/Música/Music/"

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

while true
do

cadena=$(find "$path" -iname '*.mp3')                                   #search media files
nmedia=$(echo "$cadena" | wc -l)

if [ -f "$0.his" ]                                          #file exist
then
    value=$(<"$0.his")                                      #read file

    if [[ ( $(echo "$value" | sed -n 1p) != $nmedia ) || ( $(echo "$value" | sed -n 2p) == 0 ) ]]   #reset file conditions
    then
        listrand=$(seq 1 $nmedia | shuf)
        index=$nmedia
    else                                                #no reset file conditions
        nmedia=$(echo "$value" | sed -n 1p)
        index=$(echo "$value" | sed -n 2p)
        listrand=$(echo "$value" | sed -n 3p)
        listrand=$(echo "$listrand" | sed s/" "/\\n/g)
    fi  

else                                                    #file not exist
    listrand=$(seq 1 $nmedia | shuf)
    index=$nmedia
fi

nrand=$(echo "$listrand" | sed -n "$index"p)                                #select random number
cadena=$(echo "$cadena" | sed -n "$nrand"p)                             #select song with random number
index=$((index-1))                                          #write file
echo $nmedia > "$0.his"
echo $index >> "$0.his"
echo $listrand >> "$0.his"
mplayer "$cadena"                                           #play media file

done
exit 0
```